# Possibly corrupt K8s configuration. How to find out which node is correct?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, microk8s

I am debugging a DNS issue with Microk8s on Ubuntu, where I cannot communicate with external services from inside a pod. I am now at a point, where I discovered that `microk8s kubectl get nodes` results in 2 nodes being returned, where as to my understanding there should be only one (single machine with a single installation):

```
NAME                                   STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
hostname.domain.com   NotReady   <none>   47d   v1.19.3-34+a56971609ff35a
hostname              Ready      <none>   38h   v1.19.5-34+8af48932a5ef06
```

All pods /services / controllers are running on `hostname`, where DNS does not seem to work. So I tried to remove that node from the cluster as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757620/how-to-gracefully-remove-a-node-from-kubernetes. After a restart of microk8s that node came back.

Since both nodes share the same configuration, down to the same IP, I want to try and switch over to `hostname.domain.com` as the sole node. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I lost patience and since this is a development machine, I went down the wooden route:

```
microk8s reset
sudo snap remove microk8s
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.19
```

This solved all issues.